Google Sheets - select "most recent " cell in a column and return corresponding value in same row
I'm working on a tracking spreadsheet for stock trading and want to create a "current profit/loss" cell that needs to search for the most recent "type" of trade and return a corresponding value.
Ex: Below is a scenario that shows (6) different trades and I want to select the most recent "Sold CSP" trade (in this case, 11/10/24) and return the value of $5.00.
Example Scenario
I have tried VLOOKUP, though this either always selects the first/top "Sold CSP" value of $19.50 if I make the final argument "FALSE", and if the final argument is "TRUE", it returns the bottom row with "Sold CC" and the value of $10.00.

To easily take a copy of your sample data & test formulas, the recommended method is to create a markdown table. Use this tool to create the markdown_format & add it to your question. Additionally you can also share a sample sheet showcasing your input with realistic-demo data & expected output(manually entered). You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker to ease the process of sharing


Assuming your data setup has the dates by default sorted ascending(as in screenshot), you can utilize xlookup search_mode parameter -1 (-1 is to search from the last entry to the first)
=xlookup(F4,A:A,D:D,,,-1)



This was very helpful - made this function much shorter and simpler. Thanks!
